# When to do tokenization and does my output need tokenization after stemming?

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning, preprocessing, sentiment-analysis, tokenization

I am working on sentiment analysis project , where there are various customer reviews. So I am trying to clean those reviews.

So first thing i did is removing special characters, white  spaces, numbers from text. 
Next I did is removing stop words(removing this, that, have etc.)
After that i did stemming(removing ING, ed,y etc).

Below is my output.

What I want to know is that is tokenization needed here any more?
Because my output after stemming looks like tokenization is done.
[image]

Comment: No. You need not tokenize. It is already done for you.

Comment: Ok thanks. I knew the answer but wanted to be sure.